# Best delimiter to separate multipe regex

Tags: java, regex, parsing, delimiter

I need to put multiple regular expressions in a single string and then parse it back as separate regex. Like below

```
regex1<!>regex2<!>regex3
```

Problem is I am not sure which delimiter will be best to use to separate the expressions in place of `<!>` shown in example, so that I can safely split the string when parsing it back.

Constraints are, I can not make the string in multiple lines or use xml or json string. Because this string of expressions should be easily configurable.

Looking forward for any suggestion.

**Edited:**

**Q:** Why does it have to be a single string?

**A:** The system has a configuration manager that loads config from properties file. And properties are containing lines like

```
com.some.package.Class1.Field1: value
com.some.package.Class1.Expressions: exp1<!>exp2<!>exp3
```

There is no way to write the value in multiple lines in the properties file. That's why.

Comment: Why does it have to be a single string?

Comment: Updated with the answer to your question

Comment: @Samiron there was some minor error in ans..check out the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to use **invalid** regex as delimiter such as `**` Because if it is used in normal regex it won't work and would throw an exception{NOTE:`++` is valid}

```
regex1+"**"+regex2
```

Now you can split it with this regex

```
(?<!\\\\)[*][*](?![*])
-------         -----
   |              |->to avoid matching pattern like "A*"+"**"+"n+"
   |->check if  * is not escaped
```

---

Following is a list of invalid regex

- [+
- (+
- [*
- (*
- [?
- *+
- ** (delimiter would be `(?<!\\\\)[*][*](?![*])`)
- ??(delimiter would be `(?<!\\\\)[?][?](?![?])`)

While **splitting** you need to check if they are escaped

```
(?<!\\\\)delimiter
```

Comment: it will not work for regex1 = [\d]* and regex2 =[-]+ (or any regex) , so it will form something like this: [\d]***[-]+, and split will produce [\d] and *[-]+

Answer (score 1):

Best delimiter is depends upon your requirement. But for best practice use sequesnce of special characters so that possibility of occureance of this sequesnce is minimal 
like

- $$**##$$
- #$%*&&*%$#

Answer (score 0):

i think its something helpful for u

First you have to replace tag content with single special character and then split

```
   String inputString="regex1<!>regex2<!>regex3";
   String noHTMLString = inputString.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","-");
   String[] splitString1 = (noHTMLString.split("[-]+"));
   for (String string : splitString1) {
   System.out.println(string);  
    }
```

Comment: Ah.. `<!>` is not something that i decided to use. I need a suggestion to replace it